# How can I query a strapi collection type by a field other than the id?

Tags: rest, strapi

I'd like to query an existing collection type in `strapi` via a `REST` API call by a field **other** than the `id` field.

The only option I've found is using the `filters`, e.g.

```
https://my.strapi.host:1337/api/my-collection?filters[MyOtherField][$eq]=lgNKlCLaoe2ziYqPhlJS3sNJZaRkRlcNJp38
```

To make this work, I also have to allow the `find` operation instead of `findOne` though, so this isn't really solving my question.

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this ?

Comment: @SouvikGuria no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming collection type name is **state** and we want to get state by **name** field.

> src/api/state/controllers/state.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * state controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::state.state', ({strapi})=> ({
    async findOne(ctx) {
        const {slug} = ctx.params;
        const entity = await strapi.db.query('api::state.state').findOne({
            where: {name: slug}
        });
        return entity;
    }
}));
```

> src/api/state/routes/custom.js

```
module.exports = {
    routes: [
        {
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/states/:slug',
            handler: 'state.findOne',
            config: {
                auth: false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

not modified the content in the file

> src/api/state/routes/state.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * state router
 */

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::state.state');
```

Now we can hit the API like this where "rajasthan" is the name of a state:
http://localhost:1337/api/states/rajasthan